# HHVM RepoAuthoritative Unable to stat file

Tags: php

My magento installation is hosted on a VPS running CentOS, Nginx, MariaDB and HHVM, which works without any problem.

However, I am now trying to pre-build the RepoAuthoritative file for my installation as I have read that it can provide an additional speed boost. I tried to achieve this with the following command:
`hhvm --hphp -thhbc -o /var/log/hhvm/ --input-dir /srv/www/my_magento_installation/`

HHVM then attempts to reiterate through the folder and find all php files. But the problem is I get the error message `Unable to stat file /srv/www/my_magento_installation/example_file.php`for basically every single file in the installation. An hhvm.hhbc file is created afterwards but it is by far too small and missing basically every php file from the installation directory.

I have tried to search for this error but I cannot seem to find anything helpful. I also double checking  file permissions and the files do exist. The pre-build is also unable to stat files for phpmyadmin and Piwik, not only Magento.

So my question is: why does this error message appear?